# How do amateur satellites stay consistently in the amateur-sat bands acoss the globe?

Tags: legal, satellites

I understand that my local laws may differ but amateur radio satellites, by their very nature, orbit the earth going over several legal jurisdictions.

- Are satellite bands the same internationally?
- If not, how do they keep track of which frequency to operate on?
- If a satellite is transmitting in a non-amateur band, do amateurs in the country just stay silent as it passes above?

Comment: I see from your profile that you live in Pakistan, and assume you have a Pakistani license. Have you checked your country's relevant amateur radio rules?

Comment: Hi @MikeWaters. I'm not licensed yet, the process takes time here so at the moment I can only listen. That said, what do you mean by "checked your country's relevant amateur radio rules"? I've read the laws, and even maintain a compiled [list of the designated amateur bands](https://gist.github.com/amingilani/602f20811e87874b683e3069ed57a934), but I think this question is broader than Pakistan, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: I agree - this question is about satellites, and so even though it has a 'legal' tag, adding a country tag would only confuse things. Amateur satellites are international by their very nature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple internet search turns up the IARU's [Amateur Radio Satellite Frequency Coordination](http://www.iaru.org/satellite.html) web page. There you will find an [Amateur Satellites Short Info Paper](http://www.iaru.org/uploads/1/3/0/7/13073366/short_info_paper.pdf) that answers your question:

> Satellite frequencies in bands allocated to the amateur-satellite
>   service are coordinated by the IARU Satellite Frequency Coordination
>   Panel.

As an international body operating under the UN-chartered ITU, all of the regions over which a satellite will travel should be represented.

Since frequency allocations are subject to change, I will not copy them here, but the current frequency allocations are shown by region starting on page 3 of the document.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a "simple" search ;) but thank you. Also, just for completeness, I'm going to mention here that since the Panel coordinates frequencies: yes, the satellites do operate at amateur-satellite bands across all regions they travel over.